# How to interpret normalized difference score?

Tags: normalization, differences

Lets say you have 2 variables, reaction time (RT) on an easy task and reaction time on a hard task. I've seen papers calculate a normalized difference score using the following:

$$
Z = \frac{RT(hard) - RT(easy)}{RT(easy)}
$$

How would you interpret the values of $Z$?

Say you calculate $Z$ to be 0.5, does that mean the individual is 0.5 slower on the hard task than they are on easy task? In other words we'd interpret $Z$ as how many times slower (or faster) they are on the hard task compared to the easy task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpretation is the percentage (not yet in percentage points) by which reaction time is longer for the hard task. A value of $Z=0.5$ implies that the reaction time was 50% longer in the hard task for the observation in consideration.